# cloning an object some of whose properties are objects

Tags: java, clone, cloneable

I have a bit of a special exercise, here it is:

If an **X** object has a property that contains an object then a clone of the **X** object will contain in its property the same instance that the **X** object contained.

Modify the **CloneMe** class so that if an object of class **CloneMe** is cloned then the properties **a** and **b** of the object which are also objects are also cloned but the object contained in the property **c** is not cloned.

In other words, after cloning an object of class **CloneMe**, there should be two instances of class **CloneMe** containing two different instances of **A** and **B**, but referencing the same instance of **C**.

This is the code i have to complete:

```
class A implements Cloneable {
// clone functionality hidden
     }

     class B implements Cloneable {
// clone functionality hidden
     }

     class C implements Cloneable {
// clone functionality hidden
     }

     class CloneMe implements Cloneable {
         private A a;
         private B b;
         private C c;

         public CloneMe () {
             this.a = new A ();
             this.b = new B ();
             this.c = new C ();
         }

         public A getA () {return this.a; }
         public B getB () {return this.b; }
         public C getC () {return this.c; }

         / * ---------- DO NOT MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET ON RUN ---------- * /

         / **** Enter your code here **** /

         / * ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET WHEN RUNNING ---------- * /
     }
```

Here the code i completed:

```
 class CloneMe implements Cloneable {
        private A a;
        private B b;
        private C c;

        public CloneMe( ) {
            this.a = new A();
            this.b = new B();
            this.c = new C();
        }

        public A getA() { return this.a; }
        public B getB() { return this.b; }
        public C getC() { return this.c; }

        /*----------NE MODIFIEZ PAS LE CODE AU DESSUS DE CETTE LIGNE, IL SERA REINITIALISE LORS DE l'EXECUTION----------*/

        public Clone( ) {
        private A a=null;
        private B b=null;
        private C c=null;
           }

        /*----------NE MODIFIEZ PAS LE CODE EN DESSOUS DE CETTE LIGNE, IL SERA REINITIALISE LORS DE l'EXECUTION----------*/
    }
```

sorry, I haven't found a solution yet, the problem is that I don't quite understand this notion of clone,
Do you have any leads for me please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `clone()` method in `CloneMe`. This method has to initialize `a`, `b` and `c` calling the `clone()` method of `A`, `B` and `C` classes.

Comment: i updated my code by initializing a,b et c but i don't know how to call the clone() method of classes A,B et C ,in my clone() method,do you have any idea how to call these clone() methods in my method clone()?

Comment: You have an explanation here with an example to see how to do it : https://programming.guide/java/clone-and-cloneable.html